# How can I read a cookie with a "-" in its name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I have a cookie (created by servicestack .net auth plugin) which is named `ss-id`

I can see the cookie is there in Chrome

calling:

```
cookie: <%= cookies[:ss-id] %>
```

Causes an error because of the "-" character (I'm guessing)

calling:

```
cookie: <%= cookies[:"ss-id"] %>
```

Yields nothing.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Try `cookies["ss-id"]`

Comment: isn't that exactly the same as my example? The cookie does come from the top level domain so it's in .domain.com and the RoR app is in dev.domain.com - does that affect this?

Comment: No, they are not same. `:"ss-id"` is a symbol, `"ss-id"` is a `String`

Comment: ah - missed that detail! :)

Comment: Just to clear this up - What do you mean by Symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a cookie in a view. Try creating an instance variable in the controller like this:

```
controller.rb

@cookie = cookies[:ss-id]
```

and in your view:

```
<%= @cookie %>
```

Comment: '-' cannot be part of symbol name

Comment: undefined local variable or method `cookie' for #<TestLoginController:0x3663fa8>

Comment: @BroiSatse I should be able to wrap it in quotes then surely? It's a valid cookie name

Comment: Edited answer. try cookies[:ss-id]

Answer (score 1):

If you really want your symbol:

```
cookies[:'ss-id']
```

but I guess the hash is with indifferent access so: `cookies['ss-id']` should be fine as well.

Comment: that's the one! I just got it working as you answered that. This is just a proof of concept app so no bother about this being nasty - it's only to get the core parts working as a spike